how to shade the area bounded by a curve and the horizontal lines
I would like to ask how to shade the area bounded by the curve x = (-1.5)^2+1 and {4-(x-2)^2 and the horizontal lines of y=2 and y=3.75
Here is my code
\documentclass{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=2mm 2mm 2mm 2mm}


%maths
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

%pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

%colours
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,
        width=10cm, % Width of the plot
        height=8cm, % Height of the plot
            xtick=\empty,
            xticklabels={$-1$, $3$},
            ytick=\empty,
            samples=1000,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=1,xmax=4,
            ymin=1,ymax=6]

%\node[anchor=center] at (axis cs:1.75,7.5){$y=f(x)$};

%\node[anchor=center] at (axis cs:1.75,2.5){$y=g(x)$};




\addplot[name path=F, color=blue, line width=1.5pt, domain={0:4}, samples=1000]
    ({(x-1.5)^2+1}, {x});


\addplot[name path=G, color=red, line width=1.5pt, domain={0:4}, samples=1000]
    ({4-(x-2)^2}, {x});

\addplot[name path=y1, color=black, line width=1.5pt, domain={2:3.75}, samples=1000]
    {2.5};

\addplot[name path=y2, color=black, line width=1.5pt, domain={1.49:2.5}, samples=1000]
    {0.8};



% Shading area between F and G
%\addplot[fill=black, fill opacity=0.3] fill between [of=F and G, soft clip={domain=1.49:3.75}];

%\addplot fill between[
of = F and G,
soft clip={domain y=0.8:2.5},
every even segment/.style  = {gray,opacity=.4}
];

\addplot[gray!30] fill between[of=y1 and y2,soft clip={domain=1.49:2.5}];



%plot a point
%\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:-1,1) {};
%\node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:-1,1) {$(-1, 1)$};

%plot a point
%\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:3,9) {};
%\node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:3,9) {$(3, 9)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

However the results is 
So how can I fix this? Thank you in advanced.

I can see you watched that YouTube video on LaTeX. It is a good video, but the preamble it gives is non-minimal. In the future, try to restrict it only to the bare minimum that it needs to be in order to show your problem. It really helps.
Here is a MWE that should work. Notice that I flipped the domain boundaries for the path G. This makes it so the the fill has a closed shape. Otherwise, it will criss-cross.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=F,domain={0:4},smooth] ({(x-1.5)^2+1}, {x});
\addplot[name path=G,domain={4:0},smooth] ({4-(x-2)^2}, {x});
\addplot[domain={2:3.75}]{2.5};
\addplot[domain={1.49:2.5}]{0.8};
\addplot fill between[of = F and G,soft clip={domain y=0.8:2.5}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



can you recommend me some youtube links for this one?

I'd whole heartedly recommend Dr. Trefor Bazett. That being said, eventually you will need to read the formal documentation on CTAN (Comprehensive TeX Archive Network). On CTAN you can find both the documentation and the source code for the public packages.

Instead or reversing domain, it is also possible to use \addplot fill between[of = F and G, reverse=true, soft clip={domain y=0.8:2.5}];
